# Spring Boot Batch writes empty file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I am not sure why this application is not writing anything to the file. I am reading from MySQL database and writing to a CSV file. I can see the desired resultset in ItemProcessor log but its not writing anything in the file. my file is located here resources/userinfo.csv. There is no error or exception. Spent lot of time to fix it. A help would be greatly appreciated. Here is my code

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfiguration {
    @Autowired
    public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;
 
    @Autowired
    public StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;
 
    @Autowired
    public DataSource dataSource;
 
    @Bean
    public JdbcCursorItemReader<UserInfo> reader(){
      JdbcCursorItemReader<UserInfo> reader = new 
      JdbcCursorItemReader<UserInfo>();
      reader.setDataSource(dataSource);
      reader.setSql("SELECT first_name,last_name FROM db2.userinfo");
      reader.setRowMapper(new UserRowMapper());
  
      return reader;
    }
 
    @Bean
    public UserInfoItemProcessor processor(){
      return new UserInfoItemProcessor();
    }
 
    @Bean
    public FlatFileItemWriter<UserInfo> writer(){
     
     return new FlatFileItemWriterBuilder<UserInfo>()
                .name("writer")
                .resource(new ClassPathResource("userinfo.csv"))
                .delimited()
                .delimiter(",")
                .names(new String[] {
                        "first_name",
                        "last_name"})
                .shouldDeleteIfExists(true)
                .build(); 
    }
 
    @Bean
    public Step step1() {
     return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1").<UserInfo, UserInfo> chunk(10)
       .reader(reader())
       .processor(processor())
       .writer(writer())
       .build();
    }
 
    @Bean
    public Job exportUserJob() {
     return jobBuilderFactory.get("exportUserJob")
       .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
       .flow(step1())
       .end()
       .build();
    }

}
```

UserRawMapper Class

```
  public class UserRowMapper implements RowMapper<UserInfo> {

    @Override
    public UserInfo mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
      UserInfo userInfo = new UserInfo();
      userInfo.setFirst_name(rs.getString("first_name"));
      userInfo.setLast_name(rs.getString("last_name"));
    
      System.out.println(">>> USERINFO -> " + userInfo.getFirst_name());
      // it prints fine here.....
      return userInfo;
    }

 }
```

UserInfo.class

```
  public class UserInfo {
    private String first_name;
    private String last_name;

    public String getFirst_name() {
      return first_name;
    }
    public void setFirst_name(String first_name) {
      this.first_name = first_name;
    }
    public String getLast_name() {
      return last_name;
    }
    public void setLast_name(String last_name) {
      this.last_name = last_name;
    }
  }
```

UserInfoItemProcessor.class

```
public class UserInfoItemProcessor implements ItemProcessor<UserInfo, UserInfo>{

   @Override
   public UserInfo process(UserInfo userInfo) throws Exception {
       return userInfo;
   }

}
```

application.prperties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db2?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.schema=classpath:/org/springframework/batch/core/schema-mysql.sql
spring.batch.initialize-schema=always
spring.datasource.initialize=true
```

Comment: Have you checked the content of the file by this path `<project>/target/classes/userinfo.csv`?

Comment: there is only one file and its here - workspace\sts\data-extractor-batch\src\main\resources\userinfo.csv and its empty. I am not sure why this is empty. Thank you very much for the comment!

Comment: You can check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32591542/spring-batch-java-based-fileitemwriter-for-csv. Hope it can help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring-Batch Java Based FileItemWriter for CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32591542/spring-batch-java-based-fileitemwriter-for-csv)